# How can i add the numbers of checked checkbox to this jquery / js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Please how can i add and display the numbers of checked checkboxes on this line of codes.

This is how the checkboxes works:
It has a parent and child checkbox; when i check the parent checkbox (Checkall), it checks all  (child checkboxes) and displays a div, when i each child checkbox (Single), it displays the div as well, and when i uncheck (Parent/Child) the div hides (jquery hide and show).

So, my problem here is that i want to add checkbox counter to the code. How to display the number count when i check the parent (Check all) and when i check each child (Single), and my div will still display (hide and show).

Please, help. Thanks a lot in advance.
You can improve the codes (renovate) or rewrite. Here is the code below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#global').click(function() {
    $('.child').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));

    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
      $('#mydiv').show();
    else
      $('#mydiv').hide();
  });

  $('.child').change(function() {
    var checkedLength = $('.child:checked').length;
    if (checkedLength > 0)
      $('#mydiv').show();
    else
      $('#mydiv').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">RESTORE | DELETE</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="global">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="child">
<input type="checkbox" class="child">
<input type="checkbox" class="child">
<input type="checkbox" class="child">
<input type="checkbox" class="child">
<input type="checkbox" class="child">
<input type="checkbox" class="child">
```

I'll be so glad :)

Comment: What's not working? `$('.child:checked').length` looks fine to me.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan . Please, how do i really write out the code, can you please explain make a jsfiddle of it pls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This displays the number of child checkboxes that are checked:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#global').click(function() {
    $('.child').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));

    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
      $('#mydiv').show();
    else
      $('#mydiv').hide();

    count();
  });

  $('.child').change(function() {
    var checkedLength = $('.child:checked').length;
    if (checkedLength > 0)
      $('#mydiv').show();
    else
      $('#mydiv').hide();
    count();
  });
});

var count = function() {
   var i = $('input.child:checked').length;
   $('#counter').html(i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">RESTORE | DELETE
<span>Checked: </span>
<span id="counter"></span>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="global">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="child">
<input type="checkbox" class="child">
<input type="checkbox" class="child">
<input type="checkbox" class="child">
<input type="checkbox" class="child">
<input type="checkbox" class="child">
<input type="checkbox" class="child">
```

Comment: it does not work if i check last child checkbox, it shows `0` while it should print `1`.

Comment: welldone!!!!!!!!!!!!!! but still OP has not suggested where he want to show this counter it should be visible on the page.

Comment: @John Kapantzakis . One more request please.

If a child checkbox is unchecked, the global checkbox still remains checked and if all the child checkboxes are checked, the global checkbox should be checked as well.

Also, i want re-use the code on the same page (The project is like a tabbed mail UI) so, i used the code on a tab (Inbox) and changed all the parameters for (Outbox), but not working. How can i re-use the codes again.

Thanks in advance